# Why does pause(2) not return in secondary thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, interrupt, pause

Consider this example I set up to illustrate this.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void hand(int sig);
void *thrfn(void *arg);

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    struct itimerval timer;
    sigset_t mask;
    pthread_t thr;

    act.sa_handler = hand;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);
    /* error checking omitted */

    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 500000;
    timer.it_value = timer.it_interval;
    /* ultimately I want to build a loop; hence repeating */
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);
    /* why doesn't this prevent SIGALRM from interrupting main? */
    pthread_create(&thr, NULL, thrfn, NULL);

    puts("Main thread done.");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

void hand(int sig)
{
    (void)sig;
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Handler handled.\n", 17);
}

void *thrfn(void *arg)
{
    sigset_t mask;

    (void)arg;

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);
    /* why doesn't this make pause() return in this thread? */

    pause();
    puts("Off thread's pause returned.");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Here's the output of this, compiled with gcc:

```
Main thread done.
Handler handled.
```

With about one and a half seconds between the messages.

How come my second thread's `pause` never returns?

Comment: You block signal `SIGALRM` in the thread, so who should interrupt `pause()` call for it ables to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the error is in the usage of `pthread_sigmask`. Using `SIG_BLOCK` and `SIG_UNBLOCK` instead of `SIG_SETMASK` the program behave you were expecting.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void hand(int sig);
void *thrfn(void *arg);

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    struct itimerval timer;
    sigset_t mask;
    pthread_t thr;

    act.sa_handler = hand;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);
    /* error checking omitted */

    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 500000;
    timer.it_value = timer.it_interval;
    /* ultimately I want to build a loop; hence repeating */
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);
    /* This prevent SIGALARM interrupring the main */
    pthread_create(&thr, NULL, thrfn, NULL);

    puts("Main thread done.");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

void hand(int sig)
{
    (void)sig;
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Handler handled.\n", 17);
}

void *thrfn(void *arg)
{
    sigset_t mask;

    (void)arg;

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
    /* This make the pause() return on SIGALARM */
    pause();
    puts("Off thread's pause returned.");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This program gives the following output:

```
$ ./test 
Main thread done.
Handler handled.
Off thread's pause returned.
```

It's likely you'll find your answers [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) and [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html).

In particular with:

```
sigemptyset(&mask);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);
```

you are unbloking all signals in the main thread. While, with:

```
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);
```

you are blocking only `SIGALARM` on the child thread. That is probably the contrary of what you would like to do.
Keep in mind that using `SIG_SETMASK` you specify the set of blocked signals.

Comment: Thanks! I misinterpreted SIG_SETMASK to mean its complement.